# Texture appears stretched in vertical faces of an object

Tags: texturing, materials

I am trying to apply a brick image texture on the walls (without UV unwrapping) and it appears stretched, but curiously on the ceiling, it appears correctly

[image]

EDIT: Just changed the projection in the "Image texture" node from "flat" to "Box" and it solved the problem after rendering the image, BUT in the Material viewport shading (which I want to use) still looks stretched.

Answer (score 1):

Question, did you Ctrl-A apply rotation and scale? If your mesh has not been rest to 1, then it could be causing distortion. Also, is the texture distorted ONLY in Material draw, or also in Render draw too?